# Run .NET core MVC application in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a simple .net core application with SQL server and made two images using Docker, docker-compose and pushed them to docker hub without any issue (using Windows 10).

Then using Ubuntu, tried pulling those two images and ran them and ended up with the below issue. I set environment variables in Ubuntu as well, but no luck. Docker is already installed here.

[image: Error given on Ubuntu]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're seeing this message, the image is working and the site is responding to requests. Check the site's error log and post the stack trace.

Comment: You need to  set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` inside docker-compose.yaml. Read: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers how to do that

Comment: The two comments above are correct. As far as getting everything to work you will need to create a network so that the two docker images can find each other. That's probably the root problem - the website cannot find the database server (I assume that is docker container number 2).